# Missing types namespace suds SOAP python

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm trying to create a SOAP request with suds, a python library. However I'm kind of stuck. I've researched other topics about this. But cannot solve mine. It seems that types are missing from a namespace (ns1). OK the code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor

url = "https://relatics.relaticsonline.com/DataExchange.asmx?wsdl"

imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://www.relatics.com/')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url, doctor=d, location="https://rijkswaterstaat.relaticsonline.com/DataExchange.asmx")

print(client)
```

The output is as follows:

```
Service ( DataExchange ) tns="http://www.relatics.com/"
   Prefixes (2)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      ns1 = "http://www.relatics.com/"
   Ports (2):
      (DataExchangeSoap)
         Methods (2):
            GetResult(xs:string Operation, Identification Identification, Parameters Parameters, Authentication Authentication)
            Import(xs:string Operation, Identification Identification, Authentication Authentication, xs:string Filename, xs:string Data)
         Types (48):
            ns0:Array
            ns0:ENTITIES
            ns0:ENTITY
            ns0:ID
            ns0:IDREF
            ns0:IDREFS
            ns0:NCName
            ns0:NMTOKEN
            ns0:NMTOKENS
            ns0:NOTATION
            ns0:Name
            ns0:QName
            ns0:Struct
            ns0:anyURI
            ns0:arrayCoordinate
            .....
```

There are no types with the namespace "ns1". So I cannot even make a request as I need to create an object for Authentication/Identification/Parameters.

I think something goes wrong with the schema for some reason. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is likely a bug in suds. Unfortunately the version of suds on fedorahosted is practically unmaintained. As a first step I'd recommend trying [jurko-suds](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) (a suds fork), [pysimplesoap](https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap) or [soapfish](http://www.soapfish.org) (disclaimer: I contributed to soapfish).

Answer (score 2):

The reason it did not work is because SUDS only works with SOAP 1.0. I tried to communicate with SOAP 2.0. I solved the problem by sending out a raw XML request as follows:

```
 raw_xml = """
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
      <GetResult xmlns="http://www.relatics.com/">
      <Operation>%s</Operation>
      <Identification>
                    <Identification>
                        <Workspace>%s</Workspace>
                    </Identification>
                </Identification>
                <Authentication>
                    <Authentication>
                        <Entrycode>%s</Entrycode>
                        </Authentication>
                </Authentication>
            </GetResult>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>"""

raw_xml = str.encode(raw_xml % (Operation, Workspace, Entrycode))

client = Client(url)
response = client.service.GetResult(__inject={'msg': raw_xml})
```